# Smallest eigenvalue of a sparse matrix (updated)

Tags: eigenvalues, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $D_{1}$ be $(m-1)n \times mn$ matrix (that is, $(m-1)n$ rows and $mn$ columns) and $D_{2}$ be $m(n-1) \times mn$ 
defined as
$$\begin{cases}
D_{1}[(m-1)(j-1)+i ; m(j-1)+i] & = -1 , \\
D_{1}[(m-1)(j-1)+i ; m(j-1)+i+1] & = 1 ,
\end{cases} , \quad \forall 1 \leq i \leq m-1, \forall 1 \leq j \leq n , $$
and
$$\begin{cases}
D_{2}[m(j-1)+i ; m(j-1)+i] & = -1 , \\
D_{2}[m(j-1)+i ; mj+i] & = 1 ,
\end{cases} , \quad \forall 1 \leq i \leq m, \forall 1 \leq j \leq n-1 . $$

**The main goal** is to find the smallest eigenvalue of $DD^{T}$, $\lambda_{\min} \left( DD^{T} \right)$, where
$$ D = \begin{pmatrix} D_{1} & \\ & D_{2} \\ \mathbb{I}_{mn} & \mathbb{I}_{mn} \end{pmatrix}.$$

Notation:
$D_{k} \left[ r , c \right]$ means the element of $D_{k}$ at row $r$ and column $c$.

### Example

When $m=2$ and $n=3$, we have
$$ D_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ & & -1 & 1 \\ & & & & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
and
$$ D_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & & 1 \\ & -1 & & 1 \\ & & -1 & & 1 \\ & & & -1 & & 1 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Since $m$ and $n$ are quite large, I wonder if we can find an exact formula of $\lambda_{\min} \left( DD^{T} \right)$ instead of relying on iterative method. Otherwise,
**having explicit formula for $\lambda_{\min} \left( D_{1}D_{1}^{T} \right)$ and $\lambda_{\min} \left( D_{2}D_{2}^{T} \right)$ would also be really nice**.

### UPDATE

I derived the exact formula of $D_{1}D_{1}^{T}$ and $D_{2}D_{2}^{T}$ when $m,n > 2$. Hope that it would be helpful.

1. $D_{1}D_{1}^{T}$ is a $(m-1)n \times (m-1)n$ matrix contains $n$-blocks in the main diagonal
   $$ D_{1}D_{1}^{T} = \begin{pmatrix}
   B \\ & B \\ & & \ddots \\ & & & B
   \end{pmatrix} $$
   where $B$ is a $(m-1) \times (m-1)$ matrix defined as
   $$ B = \begin{pmatrix}
   2 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 & -1 \\ & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\ & & -1 & 2 & -1 \\ & & & -1 & 2
   \end{pmatrix} . $$
2. $D_{2}D_{2}^{T}$ is a $m(n-1) \times m(n-1)$ matrix with $m$ diag contains $2$ in the main diagonal and $-1$ at the $m^{th}$-upper and lower diagonal
   $$ D_{2}D_{2}^{T} \left[ r , c \right] = \begin{cases}
   2 & \textrm{ if } r = c , \\
   -1 & \textrm{ if } \left\lvert r-c \right\rvert = m , \\
   0 & \textrm{ otherwise } .
   \end{cases} $$

Comment: Are you using the notation $A[i;j]$ to mean $A_{ij}$? Could you make the definitions of $D_1$ and D_2$ clearer, please?

Comment: Yes, it is. I will make some modification

Comment: It would help, if you could indicate the range of $i$ and $j$ in the definitions of $D_1$ and $D_2$. It is still unclear. In your small example $D_1D_1^T$ is just $2I$, btw.

Comment: I added the range of $i$ and $j$, thank you. $D_{1}D_{1}^{T} = 2I$ is just a coincidence. If you take $m=n=3$ for example we have
$$ D_{1} = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 \\ & -1 & 1 \\ & & & -1 & 1 \\ & & & & -1 & 1 \\ & & & & & & -1 & 1 \\ & & & & & & & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} $$
and you will end up with
$$ D_{1}D_{1}^{T} = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & - 1 \\ -1 & 2 \\ & & 2 & - 1 \\ & & -1 & 2 \\ & & & & 2 & - 1 \\ & & & & -1 & 2
\end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: Looks like it's still easy to find the eigenvalues of that one... By the way, is $\mathbb{I}_{mn}$ the identity matrix?

Comment: Yes. $\mathbf{I}_{mn}$ is the identity of the square matrix $mn \times mn$ :)
I also think the difficulty lies on the second one, I tried with m=n=512 and the first one still give me the result in matlab in a few seconds, but it seems to stuck in the second one...

Comment: So your matrix in case 1 is block diagonal with blocks like here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755113/what-are-eigenvalues-of-higher-order-finite-differences-matrices - so the eigenvalues are known explicitly.

Comment: got it! thank you @Dirk. Also I fould a general result for the first case
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379599001147
yet I can not found any result for the second one :)

Comment: after searching for some similar result, it comes to my mind that the eigenvalue for the second case can be obtained by using the result for the first one and the Kronecker product technique, I do not answer completely the original question but it looks fine for me. Thanks everyone for your advice and suggestion